# FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_ELEMENTS not removing empty line

Tags: php, arrays, file

I am new with the PHP file functions and i am trying to write to a
file in this manner. The data is POSTed from the Instagram real-time
subscription feed. The file always seems to contain an empty line
usually in the first few lines received.

```
  $x = fopen('activity.log', "r+");
  $myString = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $ALL = $myString."\n";
  file_put_contents('activity.log', $ALL, FILE_APPEND);
```

So, I try to "skip" any empty lines in the file with the
FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES parameter when creating an array with the
file() function, however the empty line (in this example, line 5)
shows up as an empty element in the array.

```
  $x = fopen('activity.log', "r+");
   //put file contents into an array
    $y = file('activity.log', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
   echo "<pre>";print_r($result);"</pre>";  

   Array
  (
    [0] => [{"changed_aspect": "media", "object": "tag", "object_id": "london", "time": 1406820800, "subscription_id": 9720966, "data": {}}]

    [1] => [{"changed_aspect": "media", "object": "tag", "object_id": "london", "time": 1406820802, "subscription_id": 9720966, "data": {}}]

    [2] => [{"changed_aspect": "media", "object": "tag", "object_id": "london", "time": 1406820803, "subscription_id": 9720966, "data": {}}]

    [3] => [{"changed_aspect": "media", "object": "tag", "object_id": "london", "time": 1406820803, "subscription_id": 9720966, "data": {}}]

    [4] =>
)
```

I also tried  array_filter() to remove the empty element but that does not work, so I think that the empty line is not actually empty. What
might I be missing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's some other withespace in there then, not just a newline.
A simple workaround is to filter it with [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) instead:

```
  preg_grep("/^\s*$/", file($fn), PREG_GREP_INVERT)
```

The `^\s*$` checks if there's only white `\s`pace in an array line, and _INVERT just returns those lines that aren't.

You don't need the prior `fopen()` btw.